# Creating a generic function using isset() to be used in a constructor? - PHP

Tags: php, function, isset

I am currently creating a class to handle all my form data which will then be placed into a database for future use.

Currently in my class constructor I am using the isset() function on an individual basis when I construct my variables from POST.

```
function __construct()
    {
            if (isset($_POST['first_name']))
            {
                 $this->first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
            }
            else
            {
                 $this->first_name = "NULL";
            }

    }
```

Although this example is just for one variable, I am doing this for another 12 in my php application.

As the old adage says "You cannot repeat code".

So I am trying to create a member function in my class that will be able to handle all variables, like a get/set function.

So that in my constructor all I need to do is this:

```
function __construct()
    {
            //first parameter is the member variable to be set, second parameter is the element name that the value will be POST from
           $firstname = $this->setter($firstname, "first_name");

    }

//what do I put here?
    function setter(first parameter, second parameter)
        {
                //checks the post variable has been set
                if ( isset($_POST[second_parameter]))
                return $_POST['second_parameter'];  
                else
                return "NULL";

        }
```

Can someone point me in the right direction, or with a code sample.

The aspect I am not sure about is how do I set the function to handle two parameters with a generic handle?

Thanks!

Comment: What about defining a associate array with the desired variable names and the related keys within the `$_POST` variable? You could loop over the array and check every value without cloning code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, this is a sytax error (I guess you know)

```
function setter(first parameter, second parameter)
```

also, this should issue an warning and lead to other behavior than what you want

```
isset($_POST[second_parameter]
```

you are using an undefined constant that after the warning evaluates to the string "second_parameter", you should use the variable

also, here you are using a string and not a variable:

```
return $_POST['second_parameter'];
```

another problem is the fact that you return the values, and you don't set them as members in your class

```
 if ( isset($_POST[second_parameter]))
                return $_POST['second_parameter'];  
                else
                return "NULL";
```

so maybe something like

```
function setter($first_parameter, $second_parameter)
{
        //checks the post variable has been set
        if ( isset($_POST[$second_parameter]))
        {
            $this->$first_parameter = $_POST[$second_parameter];  
        }
        else
        {
            $this->$first_parameter = NULL;
        }
}
```

might be closer to what you need

Comment: but how does it know the $first_parameter? does it just take whatever is in the function call and use it where it is needed inside the function?

Comment: I was thinking that that might be the name of a class member.. so also a string.. that you know of.. sorry if I misunderstood

Comment: I mean that you would use it like this $this->setter('firstname', 'fname'); where 'firstname' is the name of your class member and 'fname' is your key in the $_POST array

Comment: Ahh ok thanks, I think what I would do after your nice example is maybe just have the key of my POST array and just doing this in the constructor:

$this->first_name = $this->setter('first_name'); 

Thankyou for your inspiration and help! :)

Comment: @loosebruce you are welcome, I am glad if it helps. a closer look to what I mean would be this example: http://codepad.org/cNC29fdH

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm not misunderstanding - is this what you mean?

```
function __construct() {
       $firstname = $this->setter("first_name");
}

function setter($postKey) {
            if (isset($_POST[$postKey])) {
              return $_POST[$postKey];  
            }
            return NULL;
}
```

Edit:

If you want to set class properties, how about this?

```
function __construct() {
      $this->setter("first_name", "firstName"); // Post key, class property
}

function setter($postKey, $classProperty) {
            if (isset($_POST[$postKey])) {
              return $this->{$classProperty} = $_POST[$postKey];
            }
            return $this->{$classProperty} = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a lengthy, but it will help sure..here I describe all function and add by a common lib file.

class calling:

```
    <?php

     if(isset($_POST) && isset ($_POST["form_submit"])){
     $valArr=array("first name"=>$_POST['first_name '],"2nd paremeter"=>$_POST['2nd value']..and more);
     $per_obj = new Performance();
    $per_obj->addPreformance($valArr, "employee_performance");

   }
  ?>
```

employee performance class page :

```
   <?php 

   class Performance extends DataAccess{

       var $db_obj = null;
     public function  __construct() {
         $this->db_obj = new DataAccess();
    }

   public function  addPreformance($key_values = array(), $table = null) {
    $this->db_obj->table_name = $table;
    $this->db_obj->addRecord($key_values);
  $msg=$this->db_obj->msg;
header("Location: performance.php?msg=$msg");
}
   }

?>
```

common function:

```
     function addRecord($key_values)
    {

        $cols="";
        $vals="";
        foreach($key_values as $key=>$value)
        {
            if ($key!="submit" and $key!="PHPSESSID" and $key!="image_name" and $key!="submit_button" and $key!="ext" and $key!="ext2" and $key!="img_name" and $key!="mode" and $value!="" and $key!="gpl" and $key!="ip1" and $key!="ip2" and $key!="ip3" and $key!="ip4"){
                $cols .= "`".$key."`,";
                is_string($value)? $vals .= "'".addslashes($value)."'," : $vals .= "'".$value."',";

            }
        }


        $cols = substr($cols, 0, -1);
        $vals = substr($vals, 0, -1);

        $insert_qry="insert into ". $this->table_name ."(". $cols .") values(". $vals   .")";

        $r=mysql_query($insert_qry);
        $this->msg = (!$r) ? f_add_msg : s_add_msg;
        return $r;
    }
```

Comment: In any doubt or description U can ask me?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I might do.

```
class Person {
  function __construct(){
    $keystomatch = array("fname", "lname", "addr1", "addr2");
    foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
        if(!in_array($k,$keystomatch)) continue;
        $this->$k = $v;
    }
    foreach($keystomatch as $p) 
        if(!isset($this->$p)) $this->$p = "NULL";
  }
}
```